# Downloaded images are showing wrong orientation using the Android universal image loader

Tags: android, orientation, universal-image-loader

I used the android universal image loader to download the image
If I download the iOS uploaded image then it's showing 270 degree orientation.

If downloaded the s7 edge uploaded images showing 90 degree orientation

If I downloaded the Nexus mobile uploaded images are showing correct orientation

This is code I used to download the images

```
 ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true).imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY).build();

 ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.displayImage(url, image, options);
```

please advise to overcome from this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first set cacheOnDisk(false) because, It will show the previous image after you changed the code.

then changed it like this

```
  options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true).imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2).build();
```

This is solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For Image Handling I highly recommend using Picasso Library. (http://square.github.io/picasso/). You can follow their samples on GitHub if you want to learn more about it.

It automatically handles Image Scaling and other issues related to image downloading and parsing like OutOfMemory, etc.

Basic Image loading from URL can be done like this :

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView);
```